# how to remove specific sub collections in XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have below XML file

```
<Data>
 <Collection name="CD" type="Group">
  <Column name="CD">0</Column> 
  <Column name="ATXR">01/02/1753 00:00:00.020</Column> 
 </Collection>
 <Collection name="CALL" type="Group">
  <SubCollection name="CALL" type="Row">
  <Column name="PRCF">0072</Column> 
  <Column name="CDML">0</Column> 
  <Column name="ATXR">NULL</Column> 
  </SubCollection>
 </Collection>
 <Collection name="CORALL" type="Group">
  <SubCollection name="CORALL" type="Row">
  <Column name="ID">AA</Column> 
  <Column name="AMT">202.8000</Column> 
  <Column name="EX_ID">h27</Column> 
  </SubCollection>
  <SubCollection name="CORALL" type="Row">
  <Column name="ID">CE</Column> 
  <Column name="AMT">0.00</Column> 
  <Column name="EX_ID">III</Column> 
  </SubCollection>
  </Collection>
</Data>
```

and i need to remove a subcollection completely when it matches below criteria.
1) When Collection name is CORALL
2) Any Subcollection inside the CORALL which is having EX_ID starts with h

The final XML file should look like this

```
<Data>
 <Collection name="CD" type="Group">
  <Column name="CD">0</Column> 
  <Column name="ATXR">01/02/1753 00:00:00.020</Column> 
 </Collection>
 <Collection name="CALL" type="Group">
  <SubCollection name="CALL" type="Row">
  <Column name="PRCF">0072</Column> 
  <Column name="CDML">0</Column> 
  <Column name="ATXR">NULL</Column> 
  </SubCollection>
 </Collection>
 <Collection name="CORALL" type="Group">
  <SubCollection name="CORALL" type="Row">
  <Column name="ID">CE</Column> 
  <Column name="AMT">0.00</Column> 
  <Column name="EX_ID">III</Column> 
  </SubCollection>
  </Collection>
</Data>
```

Any help/idea to achieve this ?

Comment: sounds like a jolly good set of requirements.  You can do it!

Comment: I am able to read the data from the XMl file using XMLnode and for loop. What i am not able to do is removing the entire sub collection

Comment: Great! Any code to show?  This will help us help you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to locate what you're asked for and navigate to it's parent to remove the matched node:

```
foreach (XmlNode subCollection in xml.SelectNodes(
 "//Collection[@name='CORALL']/SubCollection[Column[@name='EX_ID' and starts-with(., 'h')] and Column[@name='AMT'   and . = '0.00']]"))
{
    // SubCollection.Collection.RemoveChild(SubCollection)
    subCollection.ParentNode.RemoveChild(subCollection);
}
```

Comment: Yes this works.. But if we need to search for 2 conditions like EX_ID starts with h and Amt = 0.00. Do we have a way to remove only that subcollection

Comment: I edited this answer to reflect this new requirement